# Is asking question about how muscles work a question for Health SE or Fitness SE?

Tags: discussion

Is asking question about how muscles work a question for Health SE or Fitness SE? e.g. question:

https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/17055/what-is-the-physical-reason-that-a-weak-muscle-means-that-its-antagonistic-muscl

didn't know where to put it but since I didn't address it in the context of physical fitness I put it in health but its obvious this is related to fitness, sports, movement, injuries, etc

Comment: Hrm...Let me ask the biology mods. It's not really a good fit for here or health (I'm a mod there as well).

Comment: @JohnP interesting! I would not have really considered it appropriate for there, thanks for giving me a new perspective.

Comment: The relevent part of their help page: "general questions about biological concepts". You're asking *why* does the body do this? It's not really health, it's marginal at fitness, but I would think that is squarely on topic at bio. I pinged their mods as a check.